# Create table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am making a table in Javascript for a weather forecast. This is code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++) {

  table += "<tr>";
  table += "<td>" + days[new Date(data.list[i].dt * 1000).getDay()] + "</td>";
  table += "</tr>";

  table += "<tr>";
  table += "<td><img src='img/" + data.list[i].weather[0].description + ".svg'></td>";
  table += "</tr>";

  table += "<tr>";
  table += "<td>" + data.list[i].weather[0].description + "</td>";
  table += "</tr>";

  table += "<tr>";
  table += "<td>" + Math.round(data.list[i].temp.day) + "&deg;</td>";
  table += "</tr>";
}

$("#forecastWeather").html(table);
$("#header").html(header);

$("#city").val('');

}
```

But when I use this code and open the html file in the browser this is what it look like:

[image]

And this is how it should look:

[image]

What is going wrong?

Comment: You are making multiple <tr> elements containing only one <td> each. Instead you should make one <tr> that contains multiple <td>.

Comment: otherwise if for some reason u want 1 td and 1 tr just add display: inline; in ur <tr>

Comment: Yes but how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for. Thanks guys for helping.

```js
for(var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++){

    table += "<tr>";
      for(var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++){
        table += "<td>" + days[new Date(data.list[i].dt * 1000).getDay()] + "</td>";
      }
    table += "</tr>";

    table += "<tr>";
      for(var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++){
        table += "<td><img src='img/icons/" + data.list[i].weather[0].description + ".svg'></td>";
      }
    table += "</tr>";

    table += "<tr>";
      for(var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++){
        table += "<td>" + Math.round(data.list[i].temp.day) + "&deg;</td>";
      }
    table += "</tr>";


}

$("#forecastWeather").html(table);
$("#header").html(header);

$("#city").val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
table += "<tr>";
for (var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++) {
  table += "<td>" + days[new Date(data.list[i].dt * 1000).getDay()]+"";
  table += "<img src='img/" + data.list[i].weather[0].description + ".svg'>";
  table += ""+ data.list[i].weather[0].description +"";
  table += "" + Math.round(data.list[i].temp.day) + "&deg;</td>";
}

table += "</tr>";

$("#forecastWeather").html(table);
$("#header").html(header);

$("#city").val('');
```

I am just doing table logic, I don't really understand that `table +=` thing, but you want to have just one `tr` (row) and repeat the `td`. 
If you want, you can add a table inside each row, so that u can have multiple rows inside one `td`:

```
table += "<tr>";
for (var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++) {
table += "<td>";
table += "<table>";
  table += "<tr>";
  table += "<td>" + days[new Date(data.list[i].dt * 1000).getDay()] + "</td>";
  table += "</tr>";

  table += "<tr>";
  table += "<td><img src='img/" + data.list[i].weather[0].description + ".svg'></td>";
  table += "</tr>";

  table += "<tr>";
  table += "<td>" + data.list[i].weather[0].description + "</td>";
  table += "</tr>";

  table += "<tr>";
  table += "<td>" + Math.round(data.list[i].temp.day) + "&deg;</td>";
  table += "</tr>";
table += "</table>";
table += "</td>";
}
table += "</tr>";

$("#forecastWeather").html(table);
$("#header").html(header);

$("#city").val('');
```

Comment: @JamesMiller as I said, the `table+=` thing I don´t really know how it works, i'm just explaining the table structure. I edited it, try now.

Comment: @JamesMiller Ok, I got it now.

Comment: Yes, that was the point, but I updated it, hope it helps. @JamesMiller

Answer (score 0):

It won't work like that because of the way `<tr>` and `<td>` elements are parsed. `<tr>` [represents a row](https://html.com/tags/td/), with your code you'll just end up with everything stacked on. If you really want to do it with a table, you'll have to create a `<tr>` elements with the days (first row), than another one with  the images and so on.

Generally speaking, you don't even have to use a `<table>` for this kind of layout. You can just use only one row  or, better, a bunch of floating `<div>`. Also, it's not really elegant to mix HTML and Javascript code. In this situation, I would do something like that:

```js
var table = [
  {
    day: "Monday",
    img: "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iynque/ios7-style/1024/Weather-icon.png",
    description: "Acceptable",
    temp: "20"
  },
  {
    day: "Tuesday",
    img: "https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/color/Weather/windy_weather1600.png",
    description: "Windy",
    temp: "13"
  },
  {
    day: "Wednesday",
    img: "https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/color/Weather/windy_weather1600.png",
    description: "Windy",
    temp: "16"
  }
  ]

for(var i in table) {
  
  // Select today forecast
  todayForecast = table[i];
  
  // Clone the pattern
  pattern = $('.pattern').clone()
  
  
  // Replace the vars
  pattern.find('.day').text(todayForecast.day)
  pattern.find('.description').text(todayForecast.description)
  pattern.find('.temp').text(todayForecast.temp)
  pattern.find('.img').attr('src', todayForecast.img)
  
  // Remove the pattern
  pattern.removeClass('pattern');
  
  pattern.appendTo('.dayWeatherBoard')
  
}
```

```css
.dayWeather {
  
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
 float: left;
  
}

.dayWeather img {
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
}

.pattern {
  
  display: none;
  
}

.dayWeather .day {
  
  font-weight: bold;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dayWeatherBoard">
  <div class="dayWeather pattern">
    <p class="day"></p>
    <p><img class="img" src="" /></p>
    <p class="description"></p>
    <p class="temp"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

That way, I avoid mixing HTML and JS code. Consider learning a templating or MVVM library such as Vue.js or Angular.